# How to best store an external hard drive on a motorcycle

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

When a hard drive fails from a fall, what actually fails most of the time? Does the reader head often damage the disk? If this is a big cause of disc damage caused by drops / falls / vibrations, can this risk be minimized by positioning the hard drive a certain way? Seems like storing it on its side, so the discs are vertical, would make sense so that the reader, when bouncing, would not hit the disc.

Any other thoughts about storing a hard drive on a motorcycle are welcome. Yes, I know SSDs would be ideal. In this case I'm talking about WD My Passport 2TB drives.

Comment: Most drives auto park when shut down properly, meaning the head moves off the platter, and is theoretically locked away from the drive surface.  YMMV, check the manufacturers documentation to find out if the drive does that and if it's automatic or must be manually invoked somehow.

Comment: I've seen this discussed back in the DIY CarPc days a lot.  The general consensus was: The shock system of the vehicle itself will do as much shock protection as anything further you could (reasonably) do to the HDD; so mounting it in anything, or in a certain way, isn't going to help further to protect it from shocks. And, if turning it on it's side was somehow able to protect platters from heads driven straight up or down, then the drive simply wouldn't work on it's side (as the heads could float away at the slightest variation in angle).  Get an SSD.. :)

Comment: Can you update your question to clear up the HDD capacity...2GB...TB I'll assume, but others might not :)

Comment: HDD are designed for "normal" conditions.  The vibration of a motorcycle or the crash of falling off at highway speeds is outside the conditions they're designed for.  Get one hardened for military or industrial field use (or an airplane black box).

Comment: In case you're looking for some extra protection: There are backpacks specifically designed for motorcycling. The (might) give some extra protection in case of rain and/or minor crashes. Some of them have space specifically designed laptop/hdd pockets.

Comment: Most often in this situation the heads will crash on the platters. However even if the HDD doesn't suffer such a shock it will still be exposed to an increased amount of vibrations that is likely to cause it's premature failure. The best thing you can do is make sure it's securely mounted so it won't fall off.

Answer (score 0):

Laptop hard drives have a higher shock tolerance than desktop drives do, owing to their smaller size.  Those drives typically have a non-operational shock tolerance of 300-600 G's, and an operational tolerance of 60-70 G's.

In its non-operational state, the heads are parked in a landing area off the platters, so there's no risk of damage by the heads crashing into them.  At those forces, the damage would come from a bent armature, cracked/warped platters, or the spindle bearings getting knocked off-center.

In its operating state, the heads are positioned over the platters, so the damage in that case would be from the heads making a pock-mark on the platter's surface from the impact.  The head could get broken off at that point too.

I can't tell you what kind of impact speed you'd need to generate those kinds of G-forces (that'd be more appropriate for the Physics SE site).  But I can say that if a drive mounted to your motorcycle experiences those kinds of forces, your body probably wouldn't survive that crash.

I personally have dropped an operational laptop hard drive enclosure about 5 feet onto a hardwood floor.  The drive made a sphincter-clenching klak-klak noise followed by the sound of the spindle motor getting back up to speed when it hit, but it was fine.  The enclosure probably padded the fall, as it got seriously dented.  But there was no data loss and I tested the drive OK with a surface scan.  That's more force than a drive would be reasonably expected to endure during a motorcycle ride.

Comment: 500 Gs is about the force of falling off a table onto a concrete floor.